# How to return value in a block

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am trying to return a `double` value but its not returning the desired value. I was trying different variations but was not able to return the correct value. Here you can see how I try to reach it:

```
- (double)readData
{
    __block double usersWeight;
    HKQuantityType *weightType = [HKQuantityType quantityTypeForIdentifier:HKQuantityTypeIdentifierBodyMass];
    [self.healthStore aapl_mostRecentQuantitySampleOfType:weightType predicate:nil completion:^(HKQuantity *mostRecentQuantity, NSError *error) {
    if (!mostRecentQuantity) {
        NSLog(@"%@",error);

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSLog(@"Not Available");
        });
    }
    else {
        // Determine the weight in the required unit.
        HKUnit *weightUnit;

        if([strWeightUnit isEqualToString:@"kgs"])
        {
            weightUnit = [HKUnit gramUnit];
            usersWeight = [mostRecentQuantity doubleValueForUnit:weightUnit];
            usersWeight = usersWeight / 1000.0f; //kg value
        }
        else
        {
            weightUnit = [HKUnit poundUnit];
            usersWeight = [mostRecentQuantity doubleValueForUnit:weightUnit];
        }
    }
}];
return usersWeight;
}
```

Comment: use a completion block for your original method, then you can call back that block with the desired value after you have it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call a block asynchronously. Th calling method returns, before the asynchronous block finished, so `userWeight` is unset and contains random data.

Instead of returning a value, you should pass a completion block to the method expecting the float value. Call this completion block at the end of your completion handler and pass the then computed `userWeight`. You do not need a local var outside the block.

Answer (score 1):

According to Armin i have an example for you:

```
- (void)readDataCompletion:(void (^)(double))completion
{
    HKQuantityType *weightType = [HKQuantityType quantityTypeForIdentifier:HKQuantityTypeIdentifierBodyMass];
    [self.healthStore aapl_mostRecentQuantitySampleOfType:weightType
                                                predicate:nil
                                               completion:^(HKQuantity *mostRecentQuantity,
                                                            NSError *error)
    {
        ...
        completion(weight);
    }];
}
```

Another possibility is to create a blocking method:
`dispatch_group_wait` will wait until `dispatch_group_leave` will cause leaving the dispatch group.

But keep in mind better not to call this method on main thread.

```
- (double)readData
{
    dispatch_group_t g = dispatch_group_create();
    dispatch_group_enter(g);

    __block double weight = 0;
    HKQuantityType *weightType = [HKQuantityType quantityTypeForIdentifier:HKQuantityTypeIdentifierBodyMass];
    [self.healthStore aapl_mostRecentQuantitySampleOfType:weightType
                                                predicate:nil
                                               completion:^(HKQuantity *mostRecentQuantity,
                                                            NSError *error)
     {
         weight = 123;
         dispatch_group_leave(g);
     }];

    dispatch_group_wait(g, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    return weight;
}
```